# How to solve the relationship failure?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have a processor that appears to be creating FlowFiles correctly (modified a standard processor), but when it goes to commit() the session, an exception is raised:

2016-10-11 12:23:45,700 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] c.s.c.processors.files.GetFileData [GetFileData[id=8f5e644d-591c-4df1-8c79-feea118bd8c0]] Failed to retrieve files due to {}  org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord transfer relationship not specified

I'm assuming this is supposed to be indicating there's no connection available to commit the transfer; however, there is a "success" relationship registered during init() in same way as original processor did it, and the success relationship out is connected to another processor input as it should be.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What changes did you make to the standard processor? If you are calling methods on the ProcessSession object, ensure that you are saving the latest "version" of the FlowFile returned from those method calls, and transfer only the latest version to "success".

FlowFile references are immutable; often in code you will see an initial reference like "flowFile" pointing at the incoming flow file (from `session.get()` for example), then it gets updated as the flow file is mutated, such as `flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "myAttribute", "myValue")`.

Also ensure that you have transferred or removed the latest version of each distinct flow file (not the various references to the same flow file) to some relationship (even `Relationship.SELF` if need be). If your processor creates a new flow file, ensure that new flow file is transferred. If the incoming flow file is no longer needed, be sure to call `session.remove()` on it.

There are some common patterns and additional guidance in the [NiFi Developer's Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html), including test patterns; your unit test(s) for this processor should be able to flush out this error (by asserting how many flow files should have been transferred to which relationship(s) during the test).